# How to generate migrations to reflect the current state of my database?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

During the development cycle of our application, we created several migration files, most of them are changing the same table.

Now, our application hit production and we have a lot of useless information spread across a plenitude of migration files.

It’s been a hassle to execute all of them when we need to migrate a database for development and testing purposes.

How can I compile those changes to reflect the current state of my database?

Comment: You can generate migrations from an existing database, might be a good way to build a clean slate: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Comment: Documentation is citing Laravel 4, but I can try, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "dev-l5"
}
```

The doc https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator/tree/l5

It will generate a migration for the table creation and another for the foreign keys, but after that it became easy to manually condense those migrations.